# Using CustomListItems in VSCode/Natvis

Tags: visual-studio-code, natvis

I am developing some debug visualizations for my custom classes in VSCode using Natvis.
Using CustomListItems with a simple example and I can't get it to work.
Basically, I *think* the following code should display 16 items all with value 1 but I get only the basic type of the class..

```
  <Type Name="vq23_t">
    <DisplayString>16 x q23 Array</DisplayString>
    <Expand>
        <CustomListItems>
            <Size>16</Size>
            <Variable Name="ind" InitialValue="0" />
            <Loop Condition="ind &lt; 16">
                <Item Name="{ind}"> 1 </Item>
                <exec> ++ind </exec>
            </Loop>
        </CustomListItems>
    </Expand>
  </Type>
```

**What I get:**

> pout: 16 x q23 Array
> >[Raw View]: 0x56594b40 <xin>

Spent a lot of time trying various things out so I reduced the problem to this basic level and can't get it to work.

Answer (score 1):

As described on [MSDN](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/debugger/create-custom-views-of-native-objects?view=vs-2019#BKMK_Diagnosing_Natvis_errors) you can activate logging for debugging natvis.

The solution for your case is to change the order of `Size` and `Variable` and to change `exec` to `Exec`.

```
  <Type Name="vq23_t">
    <DisplayString>16 x q23 Array</DisplayString>
    <Expand>
      <CustomListItems>
        <Variable Name="ind" InitialValue="0" />
        <Size>16</Size>
        <Loop Condition="ind &lt; 16">
          <Item Name="{ind}"> 1 </Item>
          <Exec> ++ind </Exec>
        </Loop>
      </CustomListItems>
    </Expand>
  </Type>
```

Comment: SInce i use VSCode, the MSDN link does not work for me. Any thoughts ? Also I tried the code with your changes, it still does not work - nothing is shown..  Gopal

Comment: @gopalraghavan Sortry, I did not recognize you are using VS cdoe and not VS. Yet https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/cpp/natvis links to the MSVC natvis page. But it also says that full feature set is supported for MSVC tool chain debugging but not for gdb/clang tool chain debugging. Which one are you using?

Comment: I am using gdb tool chain. So you are correct there might be differences.

Comment: @gopalraghavan Can you please check exchanging the order of the lines with `Item` and `Exec`!? https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/cpp/natvis shows `Exec` first, then `Item`.

Comment: I finally got visual studio installed and it behaved as I would expect. So it seems to be a problem specific to VSCode as you thought. I posted this to VSCode support at https://github.com/microsoft/MIEngine/issues/1095.

Comment: i tried the code with the order changed and no difference.

Comment: Simple answer: VSCode does not support loop.  Here is the answer from microsoft:  
 The default Windows C++ project uses a different natvis reader than MIEngine.
I believe MIEngine does not support Loop.

To use MIEngine in Visual Studio, you will need to create a project for WSL or use SSH for a Linux Project.

Comment: @gopalraghavan if one has no option `to create a project for WSL or use SSH for a Linux Project` and have to work with `VSCode in Linux system` then any woraround to use `natvis loop`? I am stucked in one issue, if you have time would be great if you can take a look [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72359355/extend-display-range-of-arrayitems-indexlistitems-using-natvis?noredirect=1#comment127858705_72359355).

Comment: I just reported this (and some of my other problems) to the MIEngine team: https://github.com/microsoft/MIEngine/issues/1368