# Display range of value using Natvis

Tags: c++, visual-studio-code, vscode-debugger, natvis

I have an array (`limit_array`) which is pointed by a pointer (`limit_ptr`). For simplicity, here I have given an array of length 10. Using `IndexListItems` of natvis I can iterate through the value which is pointed by the pointer `limit_ptr`. But in some cases, I would not like to see all of the values, rather my preference is to observe a range of values (eg: index 4 to 6, that means 3 values). This one is achieved but I cannot change the `index value` in the debug window. The steps I have followed are given below

##### Sample code

```cpp
int main()
{
    uint32_t limit_array[10];
    for(int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
    {
        limit_array[i] = i*5;
    }
    uint32_t *limit_ptr = limit_array;

    return 0;
}
```

##### natvis file

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<AutoVisualizer xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/vstudio/debugger/natvis/2010">
    <Type Name="uint32_t *">
      <DisplayString>Would like to observe limited or preferred ranged value</DisplayString>
      <Expand>
        <IndexListItems>
          <Size>10</Size>
          <ValueNode>limit_ptr[$i]</ValueNode>
        </IndexListItems>
      </Expand>
    </Type>
</AutoVisualizer>
```

Here, in `Size` tag I have used the length of the array.

The following output I can see in the Debug window
[image]

##### What would like to achieve

I have tried to display limited range of values. For example from index 4 to 6 I need to display. Modified natvis file as like as follows:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<AutoVisualizer xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/vstudio/debugger/natvis/2010">
    <Type Name="uint32_t *">
      <DisplayString>Would like to observe limited or preferred ranged value</DisplayString>
      <Expand>
        <IndexListItems>
          <Size>3</Size>
          <ValueNode>limit_ptr[$i+4]</ValueNode>
        </IndexListItems>
      </Expand>
    </Type>
</AutoVisualizer>
```

But I have got the output as like as follows where I can see my preferred value `20, 25, 30` but in a wrong index (still in `[0] [1] [2]`). My desire is to see them in `[4] [5] [6]`.

[image]

Is it possible by `Natvis` to observe at `[4] [5] [6]` index or it is a default behavior of `VSCode Debugger` always to display index value `0` even if it points to another index? If there is any workaround to achieve my goal would be great.

Comment: What about using `CustomListItems` instead? It seems you can apply programming logic in those expansions.

Comment: @TedLyngmo As far I can remember that one uses `Loop`,  `Exec` which is not supported by `MIEngine`. This one is stated [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65742034/using-customlistitems-in-vscode-natvis)

Comment: @TedLyngmo Also mentioned by vscode dev team that [Visual Studio MIEngine does not support Loop](https://github.com/microsoft/MIEngine/issues/1095#issuecomment-764961245)